# Use knife solo with a non-root user with sudo access, without a password

Tags: ssh, chef-infra, ubuntu-14.04, knife-solo

When I use `chef knife solo` with a non-root user with sudo access, it always asks me that user's password. However, I have turned off password access to that server.

```
$ bundle exec knife solo cook supersecretuser@productionserver -VV
Starting 'Run'
Running Chef on productionserver...
Checking Chef version...
DEBUG: Initial command sudo chef-solo --version 2>/dev/null | awk '$1 == "Chef:" {print $2}'
DEBUG: Initial command sudo -V
DEBUG: Running processed command sudo -V
DEBUG: sudo -V stdout: Sudo version 1.8.9p5

DEBUG: sudo -V stdout: Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.9p5
Sudoers file grammar version 43

DEBUG: sudo -V stdout: Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.9p5

DEBUG: Running processed command sudo -E -p 'knife sudo password: ' chef-solo --version 2>/dev/null | awk '$1 == "Chef:" {print $2}'
Enter the password for supersecretuser@productionserver:
```

I've added my ssh key to the server and am able to ssh into that server with `ssh supersecretuser@productionserver` without needing a password.

I have used `chef knife solo` on my staging server with the root user and it works fine.

I've tried explicitly passing my ssh key using the `-i` option, `chef knife solo cook supersecretuser@productionserver -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and knife solo didn't seem to use that. Any ideas on what to try next?

Note: I am showing `cook` because that's where I'm at. I did a `prepare` and it worked because I hadn't turned off password access yet - that happened with my first `cook` - so I was able to just enter the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messing between ssh and sudo, check your sudoers file for the supersecretuser entry it should looks like:

```
#Vagrant entry to allow sudo from vagrant
vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Here allowing vagrant user to sudo any command without password.

Comment: If you can't see it inside `/etc/sudoers` it's because it is inside `/etc/sudoers.d/vagrant`